# Pandas merge two dataframes to get new dataframe by matching columns

Tags: pandas, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2. df1 has columns A,B,C and df2 has columns B,C,D.
For the matching vaues in columns B,C  I want to merge both dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7], 'C': [8, 9, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [6, 7, 5], 'C': [9, 0, 8], 'D': [1, 6, 2]})
```

For example, from the above two dataframes df1 and df2 I want to get df3:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7], 'C': [8, 9, 0], 'D': [2, 1, 6]})
```

I cannot simply merge by index, as the values for B, C in the index do not match.

How do I do this?

Comment: what's wrong with `df1.merge(df2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sets` operation:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on=df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).tolist())
   A  B  C  D
0  2  5  8  2
1  3  6  9  1
2  4  7  0  6
```

According the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

> **on: (label or list)**
> Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both DataFrames. **If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames**.

So `df1.merge(df2)` works too.

Comment: you don't really need the `on`, it's done by default ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7], 'C': [8, 9, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [6, 7, 5], 'C': [9, 0, 8], 'D': [1, 6, 2]})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['B', 'C'])
```